# IIS default 404 error page not showing while browsing non existing page with.aspx extension

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, iis, webforms

We have an application hosted in IIS. The path is like `domainname/ApplicationName/page.aspx`. If I browse `domainname/ApplicationName/dgdghdhshshs` (any non existing pages without extension)it will show the default 404 page. But if I type `domainname/ApplicationName/dgdghdhshshs.aspx` (added .aspx extension) it will show the asp yellow pages. What I want is if any page or path which is not valid is accessed from browser, it should show the default 404 page. Is there any way for this?

Default 404 error page is coming automatically for other file extensions like .php, .html and .py. only for .aspx its showing yellow pages. Is there any option to bypass this for aspx page also?

Comment: As far as I known, it may difficult to disable YSOD on asp.net. When you add .aspx at the end, IIS will pass the request into the asp.net route. IIS has no way of knowing if the file exists because IIS itself is just a static file processing server. Dynamic files need to be handed over to asp.net routing to determine whether the file exists. You will find two error modules in IIS. One is Error Pages, and the other is. net Error Pages. YSOD is set in. NET Error pages. But there is no disabled button in this module. https://i.stack.imgur.com/b600h.png

Answer (score 0):

For production environment you should set in web.config file something like this:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="SomethingWentWrong.aspx">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="Http404ErrorPage.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="SomethingWentWrong.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="401" redirect="UnauthorizedAccess.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

More info about custom errors [here](https://stackify.com/web-config-customerrors-asp-net/).

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is not the custom error page. Default 404 error page of IIS is what i want instead of asp yellow page. Is it possible to mention default 404 page in the custom error section. I tried but not working.

Comment: Maybe it's a [routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/url-routing) problem?